# How to group Classes into an array? I use sequelized in my project

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I want to group classes into an array using sequelized, what should I do?
I linked 4 tables together and now I don't know how to put it into an array? Please help me

*This is my code

```
const GetInfoClass = async() => {
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let data = await db.Information_Class.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: db.Parent,
          },
          {
            model: db.Class,
          },
          {
            model: db.Subject,
          },
        ],
        group: ["id", "Classes.id", "Parent.id"],
        raw: true,
        nest: true,
      });

      resolve(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};
```

This is my result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmJ2E.png)

Comment: Please post code, data, **and results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: The value of the `data:` property is an array. Please clarify the question to show your desired output, and add your attempt to produce it.

Comment: I can't send it because stackoverflow reported an error in my data...So I took a photo of the result..Hope everyone can see it.

In the image, I want the Classes field to be an array

Comment: for example:


data: {
id:"1",
classes: [{
     id:"1", name: grade 1
    },
   { id: "2",
    name: grade 2
   }]
}

Comment: Add model and their association definitions in the post

Comment: try removing `raw: true`.